# Do I need to support both pairs of recognizers when using gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)?

Tags: ios

I'm creating a view that will support multiple gestures, and in some cases I don't want two gestures to be recognized at once. From what I understand, that means overriding `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` in the delegate. The code might look like:

```
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == swipeGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == panGestureRecognizer {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Do I need to support both pairs of recognizers? That is, based on this example, do I need to add ifs for both `gestureRecognizer == swipeGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == panGestureRecognizer` and `gestureRecognizer == panGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer == swipeGestureRecognizer`? The official [documentation on iOS' handling of multiple gestures](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures) is unclear.

I'm developing using Xcode 13.2.1, Swift 5, and the iOS SDK version 15.2 (19C51).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Under most circumstances, you probably don't even need to have a delegate for both gesture recognizers.

This message is sent to the delegates of both gesture recognizers if they both have delegates, just in case they both need to make a decision and have a say in the matter; but if they don't, then either don't give them both delegates or else, if you do give them both delegates, don't bother to implement this method in both — unless, as I say, they both have significant choices to make.

Note also that `false` is the default, so the only return value that matters is `true`, which short-circuits the process. As soon as a delegate returns `true` for a pair, the matter is settled and, even if both gesture recognizers *did* have delegates, if the first one returns `true`, the second one won't even be consulted for this pair (in reverse).